# Multiples Commands To CMD

Tags: python, command-line, ftp

I have to use The following command line tool: ncftp,
After that I need to
execute the following  commands:
"open ftp//..."
"get -R Folder", but I need to do this automatically . How do I achieve this using Python or command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Python `subprocess` module for this.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# if you don't want your script to print the output of the ncftp
# commands, use Popen(['ncftp'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
with Popen(['ncftp'], stdin=PIPE) as proc:
    proc.stdin.write(b"open ...\n")  # must terminate each command with \n
    proc.stdin.write(b"get -R Folder\n")
    # ...etc
```

See [the documentation for `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for more information. It can be a little tricky to get the hang of this library, but it's very versatile.

---

Alternatively, you can use the non-interactive commands `ncftpget` [(docs)](https://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpget.html) and `ncftpput` [(docs)](https://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html) from the NcFTP package.

I recommend reading through the documentation on these commands before proceeding.

In the comments, you said you needed to get some files, delete those files and after upload some new files. Here's how you can do that:

```sh
$ ncftpget -R -DD -u username -p password ftp://server path/to/local/directory path/to/remote/directory/Folder
$ ncftpput -R -u username -p password ftp://server path/to/remote/directory path/to/local/directory/Folder
```

`-DD` will delete all *files* after downloading, but it will leave the directory and any subdirectories in place
If you need to delete the empty folder, you can run  the `ncftpget` command again without `-R` (but the folder must be completely empty, i.e. no subdirectories, so rinse and repeat as necessary).

You can do this in a `bash` script or using `subprocess.run` in Python.

Comment: Using that code, the console opens and exits very quickly, any idea why?

Comment: The `ncftp` shell will close as soon as the `with` block ends. If you want to keep it open without using a `with` block, you can do `proc = Popen(['ncftp'], stdin=PIPE)` and then when you're done, close it with `proc.stdin.close()` (and `proc.stdout.close()` if you are capturing stdout) followed by `proc.wait()`.

Comment: Still the same, it closes inmediately and doesn't nothing.

Comment: I wonder if `ncftpget` would be a more appropriate command for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know how use it. I need get some files, delete those files and after upload some new files

Comment: I've added some instructions.

Comment: It works with ncftpget -R -DD ftp://directionofserver/remotedirectory